Convert CGPoint into SCNVector3
I want to convert CGPoint into SCNVector3. I am using ARFaceTrackingConfiguration for face tracking.
Below is my code to convert SCNVector3 to CGPoint
let point = faceAnchor.verticeAndProjection(to: sceneView, facePoint: faceAnchor.geometry.vertices[0])

print(point, faceAnchor.geometry.vertices[0])

which prints below values
CGPoint = (350.564453125, 643.4456787109375) 
SIMD3<Float>(0.014480735, 0.01397189, 0.04508282)


extension ARFaceAnchor{
    // struct to store the 3d vertex and the 2d projection point
    struct VerticesAndProjection {
         var vertex: SIMD3<Float>
        var projected: CGPoint
    }

    // return a struct with vertices and projection
    func verticeAndProjection(to view: ARSCNView, facePoint: Int) -> CGPoint{
    
     let point = SCNVector3(geometry.vertices[facePoint])
    
        let col = SIMD4<Float>(SCNVector4())
        let pos = SIMD4<Float>(SCNVector4(point.x, point.y, point.z, 1))
        let pworld = transform * simd_float4x4(col, col, col, pos)
        let vect = view.projectPoint(SCNVector3(pworld.position.x, pworld.position.y, pworld.position.z))
        let p = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(vect.x), y: CGFloat(vect.y))
        return p
    }
}

extension matrix_float4x4 {

    /// Get the position of the transform matrix.
    public var position: SCNVector3 {
         get{
             return SCNVector3(self[3][0], self[3][1], self[3][2])
         }
     }
}

Now i want to convert same CGPoint to SCNVector3.
I tried using below code but it is not giving expected values, which is SIMD3(0.014480735, 0.01397189, 0.04508282)
    let projectedOrigin = sceneView.projectPoint(SCNVector3Zero)
    let unproject = sceneView.unprojectPoint(SCNVector3(point.x, point.y, CGFloat(projectedOrigin.z)))
    let vector = SCNVector3(unproject.x, unproject.y, unproject.z)

Is there any way to convert CGPoint to SCNVector3? I cannot use hitTest because this CGPoint is not present on the node. It is present somewhere on the face area.

The code that performs the projection takes the anchor's transform into account, but the code that unprojects does not. It might be what's causing the difference.
